# Hubspot Contact Property Undefined Issue

Tags: angular, hubspot

We are using Hubspot for CRM and we do have user centric application on angular 12. When any user sign up on our portal , a contact is created on HubSpot by consuming their API key .

We notice that with some of contacts , phone number and some other properties show `undefined` and source of those actions are tagged as `Analytics` with no details .

We double check with everything related to API and even created test contacts to reproduce this issue but seems like this issue appears randomly with little to no details.

Can anyone in community guide me in some pointers or things to look into to diagnose this issue ?